# How to remove javascript type attribute in Kentico

Tags: javascript, kentico

Am trying to remove the type attribute from script tag in Kentico 10.0 application, But unable to find any solution. According to W3C validation  standards, my application throws warnings like,
"the type attribute is unnecessary for javascript resources"
[Please click here to see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVvcH.png)

Comment: Please embed one of the error rows in the question, as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - there is no real reason to remove the type attributes - it is not an error to have them.

You won't be able to remove it from each script tag easily, as many of the script tags are generated .NET itself, others generated by Kentico cannot be modified as they are generated by code compiled to a DLL file.

If you really want to remove them, as a workaround you can implement a [custom output filter](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/handling-global-events/making-custom-modifications-to-output-html).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for doing needful!

Answer (score 0):

You need to find where those script tags are being added and make modifications there. Typically they are on the master page template on the design tab on a web part or on the Master Page tab of the master page or in the layout of the master page template.

Secondly, those script includes look like they are direct from Kentico and not your custom files. Best practices say not to use Kentico's custom script files. So if you will want to make sure to not include those files or simply count them as minor errors if you're not including them because they won't be added to the page once a user navigates to a page.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I read one smiler post and it says it's not possible to remove type attribute everywhere - you can remove it in case of custom Javascript files, but script tags generated by ASP.NET and Kentico will still have this type attribute. So, in this case, I want to ask attribute generated by Kentico/.NET is actually generated from dll or what?

Comment: If you're asking specifically about the ASP.NET/Kentico generated JS files then you need to specify that in your question.  Your original question showed output of what appears to be Kentico JS files when you're logged in to Kentico viewing your page/site.  Files like `<script src="/WebResource.axd?....` are specific to asp.net and associated dlls like ajax controltoolkit.  Those you'd have to write an output filter as zolex states.  Also check https://www.kehrendev.com/blog/brenden-kehren/august-2016/improve-your-kentico-website-performance